# Production mode: what is "the best way"\"the most commonly used approach" to change and add data in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.0.9 and I have a web application running in *production* mode. I would like to change and add some data in the database (also, I would like to make that these data changes take effect in *development* mode - that is, for example, that the added data should be present also in *development mode when I am running and developing my application on my local machine*)...

... **what is "the best way"\"the most commonly used approach" to do that?** I mean, for example, should I create a migration file with in some `User.create(:name => '...', :surname => '...', ...)` statements and run those or there are other ways to accomplish what I would like to do?

*Note*: I do not need to populate the database with initial data (I already made that in the `seed.rb` file). I just need to update and add database table rows.

Comment: migrations are the cleanest way to proceed. Do you have any problem with it?

Comment: To make things cleaner, store your migration files in whatever folder you want and create customize your rake task baed on the defaults: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake

Comment: @apneadiving - No, I have no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seed.rb` should be use only for initial set of values.

`rake task` should be use only when you want to update data any existing columns.

`migration` should be use when you need to change the schema of the table.

Comment: I would like to perform a "data migration" (not changing the database schema).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the file `db/seed.rb` to accomplish this task

Here is an example on how to use it: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Comment: I used that to populate my database with "*initial*" data by using statements like 'User.find_or_create_by_name(...)'. What I can maje now in that file to accomplish what I would like to do (update and add data)?